# sum a column between two searched values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum, find

SUM "B" column between two searched values in "A" column
THEN LOOP through several hundred rows later in a seperate piece of code  I will SUM groups of SUMMED  columns

```
' find strings and sum

Sub ()  

' strings
Dim string1 As String ' first search value
Dim string2 As String ' second search value
Dim string3 As String ' third search value
Dim string4 As String ' fourth search value

' string values
string1 = "transactions for*"
string2 = "totals for date*"

' string ranges
Set string1 = Range("A")
Set string2 = Range("A")

' find strings
    If string1.Find () 'working on this
    If  Then

'working on this

End Sub
```

[image: flow chart]

[image: column data]

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible........... If not it would be an interesting exercise

Comment: SUMIF() or perhaps SUMIFS() should work, but I am assuming that the text is in one column and the data in another. Show some clear example data...

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand properly your input example and expected output. Please,  use [Table to Markdown Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) to make tables as markdown and post them in questions

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your pattern says that if both cells in columns A and B are blank, means you want to sum up there. You just need to keep storing the string value update it every time you sum up:

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StringRow As Long

StringRow = 5 'row of first string, in my case string ABC
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last non blank row in B


'Loop starting 1 row belowe first string and until last row of data
'last row of data is last one in column B!
For i = StringRow + 1 To LastRow + 1 Step 1
    
    'If cell in both columns (A and B) are blank, then next row is a new string
    'and cell in B should have the sum up from StringRow until current row stored in i
    
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" And Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B" & StringRow & ":B" & i))
        StringRow = i + 1 'update string row!!!
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Output after executing code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

This is how I've presented the data.

[image]

The initial data is in the A-column, and the sum is to be written in Cell-C2.

Here is the VBA code.

```
Sub SearchSum()
'
' SearchSum Macro
'

'
    Dim startIndex As Double, endIndex As Double
    startIndex = endIndex = 0
    Dim startingValue As String, endingValue As String, relativeStartIndex As String, relativeEndIndex As String
    startingValue = "12504" 'Sample Value
    endingValue = "12510" 'Sample Value
    Dim rowIterator As Integer
    rowIterator = 2
    
    Do While endIndex = 0
        If Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(rowIterator, 1).Value = startingValue Then
            startIndex = rowIterator
        End If
        If Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(rowIterator, 1).Value = endingValue Then
            endIndex = rowIterator
        End If
        rowIterator = rowIterator + 1
    Loop
    
    relativeStartIndex = startIndex - Range("C2").Row
    relativeEndIndex = endIndex - Range("C2").Row
        
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(R[" + relativeStartIndex + "]C[-2]:R[" + relativeEndIndex + "]C[-2])"
End Sub
```

This is how the sheet looks after the Macro is run.

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I tried the suggested markdown and the returned data was scattered all over. so I didn't insert it  I am inserting a .JPG image, I hope.... I am studying the code you presented NEW GUY. I am going to try to insert image, my presentation was poor at best.

Comment: I added a flow chart, and what the column data looks like

Comment: Foxfire And Burns And Burns, thanks for your input also, I am suprised  at the many ways to do the same thing.